# Translating Obj-C blocks into Swift for AFNetworking calls

Tags: swift, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to use AFNetworking in a Swift doc (this is a necessary constraint, otherwise I'd love to learn AlamoFire). I'm struggling with what to do here, as someone quite new to Swift:

```
- (nullable AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(nullable id)parameters
                        success:(nullable void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                        failure:(nullable void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation * __nullable operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

In particular, I'm not clear what to do for the failure blocks. Here's my attempt:

```
manager.GET(
"random_url",
parameters: [...random parameters...],
success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
responseObject: AnyObject!) in
print("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
},
failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
        print("there was an error")
}
)
```

I'm getting an error for my `failure` block:

`Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((AFHttpRequestOperation?, NSError) -> Void)?'`.

I'd appreciate if folks can tell me where I'm going wrong above. Many thanks.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ did you read my message? that choice is not in my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it isn't clear from the error, but I had a similar issue when porting our Swift 2 app to Swift 3. The issue, at least for us, was regarding the parameters in the closure. Instead of a forcefully unwrapped optional, specify them as optional types. In other words, try:

```
failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, error: NSError?) in
    print("there was an error")
}
```

Again, the error doesn't seem to indicate that as the issue, but this is exactly what we ran against three months ago.

Comment: Thanks very much! that was exactly the problem.

Comment: Glad it helped! I know how frustrating it was when we dealt with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed the "in":

```
failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
        print("there was an error")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I made that code correction but the error message remains the same, even after a code clean.